# Create a table with weights

Tags: dataset, stata

I am using Stata to create a table summarizing numbers of observations by weights.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
Gender Education Weights
  1        2       1.2
  1        1       0.5
  2        2       3.0
  2        2       1.3
```

I would like to create the following table:

```
           Education1   Education2
Gender1         0.5         1.2
Gender2          0          4.3
```

So I sum the numbers of observations weighted by the third column in the corresponding entry. For example, with `Gender2` and `Education2`, I have two observations and they have weights `3.0` and `1.3` respectively. As a result, I just calculate `1.3*1 + 3.0*1 = 4.3`.

Is there any simple way in Stata to create such a table?

As long as the numerical entries are correct, row names and column names do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `collapse` to reduce your dataset in any way you want.
In your example

```
#create the weighted observations
gen full_obs = education * weights

#aggregate
collapse (sum) education = full_obs, by(gender)
```

and then you can `reshape` your data if needed.

Comment: It is not I wanted. This code creates a one-way table.

Comment: reshape it, bro

Comment: I don't see that any restructuring of the dataset is needed at all. It's a slightly nonstandard tabulation problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabulate` command to produce the desired output:

```
clear 

input Gender Education Weights
1   2   1.2
1   1   0.5
2   2   3.0
2   2   1.3
end 

tabulate Gender Education [iw=Weights] 

           |       Education
    Gender |         1          2 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |        .5        1.2 |       1.7 
         2 |         0        4.3 |       4.3 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |        .5        5.5 |         6
```